# Use generic UpdateView to always edit a single configuration object

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

## What I Need

I want to have a global configuration for my app and I want to reuse a generic `UpdateView`.

## What I Tried

For this purpose I created a model (example fields):

```
class Configuration(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=23)
```

A generic Updateview:

```
class ConfigurationView(UpdateView):
    model = Configuration
    fields = ['admin','hostname']
```

And *urls.py* entry

```
path(
    'configuration/', 
    views.ConfigurationView.as_view(
        queryset=Configuration.objects.all().first()
    ),
    name='configuration'
),
```

As you can see I want the *configuration/* path to link to this configuration and always only edit this one object.

## Problem

I get the error

> AttributeError: 'Configuration' object has no attribute 'all'

## Questions

1. How can I hardcode the object into the path in *urls.py* so that always the first Configuration object is used for the `UpdateView`?
2. Is there a better way to do this? I simply want to have a global configuration object and want it to be editable and displayable with a template of my choice.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to provide a single object to a class expecting a queryset. The view calls `get_queryset` which does this;

```
def get_queryset(self):
    """
    Return the `QuerySet` that will be used to look up the object.
    This method is called by the default implementation of get_object() and
    may not be called if get_object() is overridden.
    """
    if self.queryset is None:
        if self.model:
            return self.model._default_manager.all()
        else:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                "%(cls)s is missing a QuerySet. Define "
                "%(cls)s.model, %(cls)s.queryset, or override "
                "%(cls)s.get_queryset()." % {
                    'cls': self.__class__.__name__
                }
            )
    return self.queryset.all()
```

You've provided a queryset so that lands on `self.queryset.all()` which for your example is calling `all()` on an instance of your class.

To use the `queryset` kwarg of `as_view()` you'd do something like `MyView.as_view(queryset=MyModel.objects.filter(enabled=True))`

So you need to change the way the view looks for the object;

```
class ConfigurationView(UpdateView):

    def get_object(self):
        return Configuration.objects.first()
```

By default `UpdateView` does this to get an object; https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/

If you're limiting the config to 1 object you will also want to implement a Singleton design. Essentially this is a way to ensure only 1 object can exist. Read more here; https://steelkiwi.com/blog/practical-application-singleton-design-pattern/

There is a really helpful package for singletons called [django-solo](https://github.com/lazybird/django-solo)